# jintellitype just work as developer but not in a client machine (JAVA)

Tags: java, jintellitype

I've developed a java swing application that read barcodes from a folder that contains tif image and show it on a TextField. 
I've used the "jintellitype" to create shortcuts (Windows + 'A') to copy to the Clipboard each code read.
When I  exported the project as a runnable jar, the dll was within the project root folder. In my machine this jar works perfectly, but when I try to execute this jar in another machine, I receive the message that could not load JIntellitype.dll from local file system or from inside JAR. 
I dont know what is the reason for it runs in my computer and in other no. Both have the same jre instaled and are windows7 64 bits.
Could you help me please?

Comment: Sounds like the DLL isn't in the Jar file like you think it is.  Have you tried placing the DLL file in the folder where you're deploying it?

Comment: yeah, I've already done it.. I've created a folder in the client's workspace and into it I've put my application's jar and the dll file. The most stranger is if a client has an installed jdk , my application's jar works fine.